# What is the correct way to compile a file using Embeddable Common Lisp?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, lisp, common-lisp, ecl

I attempting to use ECL to create a .o file with the intention of using its feature of compiling to C however I am receiving an error when trying to build a program as the documentation lists.

I am running:

```
(c:build-program "CompiledFile" "hello.lisp")
```

An receiving the error:

```
Debugger received error of type: SIMPLE-ERROR
Cannot find the external symbol BUILD-PROGRAM in #<"C" package>.
Error flushed.
>> "CompiledFile"
>> "hello.lisp"
>> ;;; Warning: Ignoring an unmatched right parenthesis.
```

The contents of hello.lisp are as follows:

```
(defun say-hello ()
  (print "Hello, world"))

(say-hello)
(terpri)
(quit)
```

I am following the documentation found here https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/static/manual/ch34s03.html and it has the function definition as:

`c:build-program {image-name &key lisp-files ld-flags prologue-code epilogue-code}`

Comment: The contents of `hello.lisp` are irrelevant, it's complaining that `c:build-program` doesn't exist.

Comment: Try `c::build-program` in case it's not exported for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar Running c::build-program just gets me a similar error `Condition of type: UNDEFINED-FUNCTION
The function C::BUILD-PROGRAM is undefined.
Available restarts:

1. (RESTART-TOPLEVEL) Go back to Top-Level REPL.

Broken at SI:BYTECODES. [Evaluation of: (C::BUILD-PROGRAM "CompiledFile" "hello.lisp")] In: #<process TOP-LEVEL>.`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. All the ECL documentation says that this function should be there. Are you sure you're using ECL and not some other CL implementation?

Comment: @Barmar yep, using installed prebuilt from https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/static/files/prebuilt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://ecls-list.narkive.com/xACoJUbf/c-build-program-and-eval the compiler isn't loaded by default, you need to use

```
(require 'cmp)
```

first.

I'm not sure why this isn't mentioned in the manual.

Comment: That definitely seems to be the right direction but I encountered a strange issue when using it, `> (require 'cmp)
;;; Loading #P"C:/Program Files (x86)/ECL/cmp.fas"

Condition of type: SIMPLE-ERROR
LOAD: Could not load file #P"C:/Program Files (x86)/ECL/cmp.fas" (Error: "The operation completed successfully.
")
Available restarts:

1. (RESTART-TOPLEVEL) Go back to Top-Level REPL.

Broken at SI:BYTECODES. [Evaluation of: (REQUIRE 'CMP)] In: #<process TOP-LEVEL>.` and then I received the same errors when trying again. (cmp.fas is in the directory)

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to tell you. I don't have Windows so I can't try it myself.

Comment: All good, at least I've made some progress towards fixing it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

According to [ECL manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/static/manual/System-building.html), you need to initialize C/C++ compiler to generate the .o files:

```cl
(ext:install-c-compiler)
(compile-file "hello.lisp" :system-p t) ; Now this produces .o file
```

To generate an executable from .o:

```cl
(c:build-program "CompiledFile" :lisp-files '("hello.o"))
```